# any way to show my application made in IONIC on apple devices?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am developing an application in IONIC, my clients are users of apple products. obviously I can not do as in android simply by sharing the apk, in ios should register the device first and I do not have the ability to physically see them and connect their cell phones to my computer. what alternative or what means should I use to show the compilation result in ios? (no need to go to stores)

I would like some way something like sending a link or they can download something so they can see my application. my clients do not know much about this topic, so they want to see the application working in some way.

Comment: Either go with testflight which is quite a pain in the *ss to set up or host your app somewhere online and show it to your customers in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

For pure visual feedback, you can deploy your project in the lab mode:

```
ionic serve -l
```

Also, you can install a virtual machine with MacOS on it (or install a second operating system on your current machine) and execute the iOS-project with xCode.
For native funcionality there is pretty much no way around getting a physical device.

Comment: I would like some way something like sending a link or they can download something so they can see my application. my clients do not know much about this topic, so they want to see the application working in some way.

Comment: Never worked with it, but Apple offers a framework for that: https://developer.apple.com/testflight/

Comment: Is it necessary to upload to the appstore to send the application to testFlight? or I can simply compile my project and send it to TestFligth...

Comment: Well you will need to upload your build. Even if you need to upload it to the AppStore, it won't be public or released in any way. At least this is, what the homepage says,

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.apple.com/testflight/ is what you are looking for.

Here are the broad steps:

Build your app and make sure you like what you see when you do the 
$ionic serve

Test locally.

Then add ios platform and build for it.

Then open the platforms/ios folder in XCODE.

Choose a Developer Team (for signing in the General tab).

Press command + shift + K to clean 
and 
command + B to build

Then select Project -> Archive to create an archive that you can upload to iTunes and share to testers.

More details: 
https://www.raywenderlich.com/190493/testflight-tutorial-ios-beta-testing-2

Answer (score 0):

You could generate a PWA and then just share the link to your clients.

Comment: Investigate a bit ;) https://ionicframework.com/pwa The users will be able to reproduce your app without downloading the app